# How to create uneven rounded sides on a div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, rounded-corners

I've been trying to make a DIV with uneven rounded sides like this:

[image]

I've checked some solutions and the closest I can get to it is by using border-radius. I've used:

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 80%50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 30%30px;
```

And this is what I've got:
[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can consider [`clip-path`](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  clip-path: circle(75% at 65% 10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or use [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 10%, blue 75%,#0000 75.5%);

}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or use a pseudo element with `border-radius` and rely on overflow

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 -10% 10%;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

And let's don't forget the SVG solution (as a regular element or background)

```css
svg {
 display:inline-block;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64'  width='200' height='200' fill='blue'> <path d='M0 0 L0 28 C10 46 30 60 64 48 L64 0 Z' /></svg>")0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<svg
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  viewBox='0 0 64 64'
  width='200' height='200'
  fill='blue'>
  <path d='M0 0 L0 28 C10 46 30 60 64 48 L64 0 Z' />
</svg>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

*Here is a good online tool to easily adjust the SVG  [`http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0 0 L0 28 C10 46 30 60 64 48 L64 0 Z`](http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0%200%20L0%2028%20C10%2046%2030%2060%2064%2048%20L64%200%20Z)*

---

You can also consider [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image):

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:blue;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 10%, #fff 75%,#0000 75.5%);
          mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 10%, #fff 75%,#0000 75.5%);

}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Here is another syntax for the `radial-gradient` solution without the use of `at` which [is not supported in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54215315/8620333)

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(blue 60.5%,#0000 61%) 35% 100%/200% 200% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: None of the above solution works in my case. I need left border curve not bottom. I need all browser supported solution

Comment: @SagarKodte you need *to adjust* the code to have your left border. Don't expect to get a ready-to-copy-past code. This answer gives you all the possible ways

Comment: I tried your pseudo element css solution but it's not getting as per design even changing the border-radius property and other solutions are not supported by some browsers like edge and safari

Comment: Even there are some other points in my question which is not related to this question.

Comment: This one of the most informative answers I have ever seen , thank you.