# How to place dropdown div over clip-path?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a dropdown div over a clip-path without success. I tried to use z-index with position fixed without success.
Is there a way to keep the clip-path and force the dropdown content div to be place over it ?

I did a jsfiddle which demonstrate the problem below

Thank you in advance for your help !

**JSFiddle :**

```
JSFiddle below
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ksenechal/6ognyres/7/

Comment: short answer : no

Comment: Not as long as you keep the dropdown element inside the container that gets clipped. You can not chop off your arms, and then still expect to be able to do handshakes when meeting people :-)

Comment: to get more ideas instead of clip-path : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091526/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/50439581/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to do that by adding an additional background layer.
I have modified your code:

```css
.header__top {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 92px;
  padding: 0 32px;
}
.back-ground {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  height: 84px;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: #0068b0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  clip-path: url("#appMenuMask");
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
.app-sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  height: 84px;
  padding-top: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.app-sub-menu-without-clip {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  height: 84px;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: #0068b0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.dropdown .icon {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  fill: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  padding: 5px 36px 5px 10px;
}

.dropdown-content li.child-link {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background-color: #ffc301;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content>li>a:after {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-family: PTSans-Regular;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  color: #0173c2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown .show {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
        <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 960 84">
        <clipPath id="appMenuMask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <polygon points="0 72,487 84,960 72,960 0,0 0" transform="scale(0.001041667 0.011904762)">
          </polygon>
        </clipPath>
      </svg>
        <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 900 1002">
        <defs>
         
        </defs>
      </svg>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
      <symbol id="hexagon" viewBox="0 0 492 552">
        <path d="M270.855 6.652l196.24 113.15A49.76 49.76 0 0 1 492 162.907V402.31a26.88 26.88 0 0 1-13.453 23.286L270.855 545.348a49.76 49.76 0 0 1-49.71 0l-196.24-113.15A49.76 49.76 0 0 1 0 389.093V162.908a49.76 49.76 0 0 1 24.904-43.107L221.145 6.652a49.76 49.76 0 0 1 49.71 0z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </symbol>
      </svg>
      </div>
      <p>
        How to keep clip-path and have dropdown content appear over it ?
      </p>
      <header id="header" class="app-header">

        
        <div class="app-sub-menu">
        <div class="back-ground"></div>
          <ul class="app-nav">
            <li>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">With clip-path</a>
                <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content show">
                  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                  <li class="child-link"><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                  <li class="child-link"><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="app-sub-menu-without-clip">
          <ul class="app-nav">
            <li>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Without clip-path</a>
                <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content show">
                  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                  <li class="child-link"><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                  <li class="child-link"><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you @Daniil, it was definitively the best solution to solve my problem :)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem/question, but this answer contains so much code and so little explanation that I can't understand what the key to making it work is. What is it about your solution that enables the menu to "break out" over the top of that clip-path?